# Does the healing from leaders and supply wagons stack?

Tags: rise-of-nations

In rise of nations with the building of Versailles does the healing effect from the wagons stack with the health bonuses of the Healing Leaders? The French have the ability to have their supply wagons heal at double the rate of the original ones after the building of Versailles. Also the Patriot/President and CEO all give healing benefits. So what is the maximum amount of health regeneration that you can have in Rise of Nations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that a normal general will heal 1 hp every second. With 1 supply wagon also it heals 2 hp per second. After 5 supply wagons I discovered that the maximum amount of hp gained is 5hp per second. This makes it possible for the healing effects to stack.